# firestore ограничение длины массива на запись

Tags: firebase, firestore

В документе есть поле

```
myProp
[
   someid_0,
   simeid_1,
   ...
]
```

Как можно ограничить размер массива?
Я делаю так:

```
allow write: if  request.auth.uid == userId  &&
            request.resource.data.myProp.length() < 2;
```

Но это так, наугад, потому что документация максимально убогая, особенно о правилах...

Как то возможно это проверить? Функции не предлагать - мне не нравится такое решение. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. (У меня было разрешающее правило ниже, которое отменяло это)
Правильно так:

```
 request.resource.data.myProp.size() < 2;
```